# Mongoose MongoDB find the one with smallest array-length of an array-field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

I need the document in a collection that has the least array size of a field among all.
Document looks as follows:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("jsd273rsdjkvn847ckjnas74"),
    "associatedUsers": [
        ObjectId("jsd273rsdjkvn847ckjnas75"),
        ObjectId("jsd273rsdjkvn847ckjnas76")
    ]
}
```

Out of all the documents in MongoDB, I need to find the one with least number of associatedUsers in its array. Basically the one with shortest array length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to calculate new field based on array [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) and then use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) along with [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to get the document with smallest array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            size: { $size: "$associatedUsers" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { size: 1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kdTyV7-4EeD)